# The Dynamics 365 plugin preimage contains the value after modification

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

The plugin step's message is Assign, postoperation (or preoperation, or prevalidation, the problem is still the same). When I debug the plugin in Visual Studio, the field "ownerid" of the preImage does not contain the Id of the old user, but the newly assigned one.

```
leadPreImage.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("ownerid").Id
```

What can be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AssignRequest is currently deprecated and is likely to be removed in a future release. Consider changing your plugin step to Update Message and add Owner(ownerid if looking in schema names column) as a filtering attribute for a better performance.

I believe this will remove your issue.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I did, but I wanted to know why it did not work with the assign message. Do you have an article that states that the assign message is deprecated? @André Cavaca

Comment: Check the official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.assignrequest?view=dynamics-general-ce-9#remarks)